# How do I rename a file and then find it again in few lines in python?

Tags: python

I use os.rename as so:

```
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(o)
x = id_generator()
ll = os.rename(o, x + file_extension)
```

`id_generator()` just makes a random string, and it does rename the file like I want it to, but since `os.rename()` doesn't offer anything of value, I can't use it as a variable. All I need is to be able to find the renamed file in as few lines as possible and be able to set it as a variable.

`id_generator()` generates a string that has 6 characters and can be numbers and letters.

Comment: `new_name = x + file_extension; os.rename(o, new_name)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply store the concatenated string in a new variable before you rename the file.

```
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(o)
x = id_generator()
# Store new name before os.rename()
new_file = x + file_extension
os.rename(o, new_file)
```

Now you can use `new_file` in the rest of the logic.